# Overloading Binary Operators within Template Class doesn't allow access to private data members

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I am pretty sure I am just doing something dumb, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Original code below...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class set
{
public:
    void add(T newElement);
    void remove(T newElement);
    bool contains(T aValue);
    int size();
    void print();
    set<T> get();
friend set<T> operator-(const set<T>& set1, const set<T> set2){

}
friend set<T> operator&(const set<T>& set1, const set<T> set2){

}
friend set<T> operator|(const set<T>& set1, const set<T> set2){

}
private:
    vector<T> setVec;
};
template <class T> 
void set<T>::add(T newElement){
    setVec.push_back(newElement);
}
template <class T>
void set<T>::remove(T newElement){
    it = find(setVec.begin(), setVec.end(), newElement);
    setVec.erase(it);
}
template <class T> 
void set<T>::print(){
    for (vector<T>::iterator it = setVec.begin(); it != setVec.end(); ++it){
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
    if (setVec.empty()){
        cout << "SET is empty." << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main(){

    set<int> s;
    s.add(1);
    s.add(2);
    s.add(3);
    s.print();

    set<int> s3;
    s3.add(6);
    s3.add(5);
    s3.add(3);

    set<int> s4 = s | s3;
    s4.print();

    set<string> s2;
    s2.add("a");
    s2.add("b");
    s2.add("c");
    s2.print();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I am just trying to overload the |, &, and the -  operators for set operation functions. I understand how I can implement the solution, but despite the member functions being friends, I can't access the private data members of the parameters I am passing in.

Any ideas?

Comment: It compiled fine for me (apart from some methods not returning anything when they should).

Comment: It compiles fine. But, if I try to do set1.setVec, I can read its private members. I need that so I can implement the operators.

Comment: Where are you calling that from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operators marked with `friend` look and work just fine:

```
friend set<T> operator|(const set<T>& set1, const set<T> set2){
    cout << set1.setVec.at(0) << " " << set2.setVec.at(0) << endl; // I am accessing private variable setVec here
    set<T> ss; // Some new set to return
    return ss;
}
```

Note that `set2` should also be passed as a `const` reference (same as `set1`). Also, consider changing the name of your class, as there is already a `set` in the `std` namespace.

Comment: Thank you. I am a dummy. I was just going by the shortcuts in visual studio. I should have actually checked it. Long day for and thanks again.